# c# WPF Filter list of controls

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, filtering, listcollectionview

Has anyone tried filtering lists of controls? I have some simple sample code that will illustrate an issue that I can't seem to get around. When filtering lists of text I have no issues but when I turn the list into an observable list of controls any filter I run effects the other filters. Here is some sample code that works

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> testOC { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        testOC = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            testOC.Add("Test Stuff " + i);
        }

        ListCollectionView view1 = new ListCollectionView(testOC);
        ListCollectionView view2 = new ListCollectionView(testOC);
        view1.Filter = Filter1;
        view2.Filter = Filter2;
        leftGrid.ItemsSource = testOC;
        MiddleGrid.ItemsSource = view1;
        rightGrid.ItemsSource = view2;
    }

    private bool Filter1(object test)
    {
        try
        {
            var testStuff = test as string;

            if (testStuff.Contains("1"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    private bool Filter2(object test)
    {
        try
        {
            var testStuff = test as string;

            if (testStuff.Contains("2"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<Window x:Class="testTheFilter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testTheFilter"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="775"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Name="leftGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <ItemsControl Name="MiddleGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <ItemsControl Name="rightGrid" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Screenshot of code working:
[image: code working]

This works as it should, you get three lists the first list contains all strings, the second contains only strings with 1's, and the third list contains only strings with 2's.

Now if I take that exact same code and change it to a list of controls it gets wonky

Here is code part:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Button> testOC { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        testOC = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = "Test Stuff " + i;
            testOC.Add(btn);
        }

        ListCollectionView view1 = new ListCollectionView(testOC);
        ListCollectionView view2 = new ListCollectionView(testOC);
        view1.Filter = Filter1;
        view2.Filter = Filter2;
        leftGrid.ItemsSource = testOC;
        MiddleGrid.ItemsSource = view1;
        rightGrid.ItemsSource = view2;
    }

    private bool Filter1(object test)
    {
        try
        {
            var testStuff = test as Button;

            if (testStuff.Content.ToString().Contains("1"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    private bool Filter2(object test)
    {
        try
        {
            var testStuff = test as Button;

            if (testStuff.Content.ToString().Contains("2"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of code not working:
[image: code not working]

Has anyone seen this behavior before and does anyone know how to fix this? I've spent hours researching this and can't seem to find a fix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose that's because one visual element can't be a child to several parents (as you can see all the buttons are unique in your second example). Do you really need to make that in code? DataTemplate can be the tool for the job here.

Comment: I don't know much about DataTemplates...I suppose this will be a good time to look into it. The reason for the program I'm creating is my department monitors system tasks that we have created in the Task scheduler. I created user controls that a visual representation of those tasks. I have 4 columns I want to display depending on the view the user has picked. One that displays all tasks, one that displays erred tasks, one that displays disabled and one for running or active tasks. Not sure if that sheds any light on what I'm doing.

Comment: Just continuing to look into this and I can't seem to see how this fixes my issue...I'll keep looking into but if anyone has a solution or idea please feel free to share it.

Comment: I still don't know why you need buttons here, but data templates were created exactly for changing the visual representation of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can't add one visual element (Button) to different parents at the same time, why not use [DataTemplates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)? If you keep the code from your frist example, just edit the XAML and you're ready to go:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate">
            <Button>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="775"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Name="leftGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" />
    <ItemsControl Name="MiddleGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" />
    <ItemsControl Name="rightGrid" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This example was the key. I still have a lot of work to do binding the data from the usercontrol to the datatemplate but this fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like [icebat said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086937/c-sharp-wpf-filter-list-of-controls#comment59821099_36086937), one visual element can't be a child to several parents.  Button is a visual element - string is not.  If you change your code to this, you get the disired result:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Button> testOC { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Button> testOC1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Button> testOC2 { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        testOC = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
        testOC1 = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
        testOC2 = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var content = "Test Stuff " + i;

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = content;
            testOC.Add(btn);

            Button btn1 = new Button();
            btn1.Content = content;
            testOC1.Add(btn1);

            Button btn2 = new Button();
            btn2.Content = content;
            testOC2.Add(btn2);
        }

        ListCollectionView view1 = new ListCollectionView(testOC1);
        ListCollectionView view2 = new ListCollectionView(testOC2);
        view1.Filter = Filter1;
        view2.Filter = Filter2;
        leftGrid.ItemsSource = testOC;
        MiddleGrid.ItemsSource = view1;
        rightGrid.ItemsSource = view2;
    }
```